# I'm using gsap and nuxt3 but when resize the window the animation don't work the animation is for horizontal scrolltrigger

Tags: javascript, gsap, nuxtjs3

**this is my code and I made refresh scroll trigger but it still don't work and the animation when resizing the window is go to the bottom and top and don't stop the animation under 800px but when I resize and the reload the page it work as expected please help because I am very stuck in this code **

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import axios from "~/services/axios.js";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import { CheckBadgeIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/24/solid";
import paint from "../../assets/images/paint.jpg";
import t1 from "../../assets/images/true/t1.jpg";
import t2 from "../../assets/images/true/t2.jpg";
import t3 from "../../assets/images/true/t3.jpg";
import t4 from "../../assets/images/true/t4.jpg";
import t5 from "../../assets/images/true/t5.jpg";
import t6 from "../../assets/images/true/t6.jpg";
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const data = [
  { image: t1, text: "amjad" },
  { image: t2, text: "amjad" },
  { image: t3, text: "amjad" },
  { image: t6, text: "amjad" },
  { image: t4, text: "amjad" },
  { image: t5, text: "amjad" },
];

const initAnimation = () => {
  const section_2 = document.getElementById("horizontal");
  let box_items = gsap.utils.toArray(".horizontal__item");

  gsap.fromTo(
    box_items,
    {
      xPercent: 30 * (box_items.length - 1),
    },
    {
      xPercent: -120 * (box_items.length - 1),
      ease: "sine.out",
      // duration: 5,

      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: section_2,
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1,
        // markers: true,
        snap: 1 / (box_items.length - 1),
        end: "+=" + section_2.offsetWidth,
        toggleActions: "restart pause reverse reverse",
      },
    }
  );
};

let scrollTriggerInstance;

const features = ref([]);
const featuresFor = ref([]);
const error = ref(null);
const isLoading = ref(false);



onMounted(() => {
  // fetchChoicesData();

  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    ScrollTrigger.refresh();
  });

  const handleResize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 800 && scrollTriggerInstance) {
      // Kill the ScrollTrigger instance and animation if screen size is less than or equal to 800px
      ScrollTrigger.refresh();
      scrollTriggerInstance.kill();
      scrollTriggerInstance = null;
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 800 && !scrollTriggerInstance) {
      // Initialize the animation if screen size is more than 800px
      ScrollTrigger.refresh();
      scrollTriggerInstance = initAnimation();
    }
  };

  if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
    scrollTriggerInstance = initAnimation();
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
});


ScrollTrigger.refresh();
</script>
  

<template>
  <div class="w-full">
    <h1 class="text-white text-[3rem] sm:text-[5.5rem] leading-[5rem] font-[600] mb-[2.2rem] ">Pracht <br> Abonnement</h1>
    <!-- <div
      id="horizontal"
      class="horizontal w-full big:px-0 px-[1.5rem] big:pb-0 pt-[4rem] pb-[8rem] big:py-[10rem] relative"
    >
      <div class="container w-[95%] m-auto">
        <div class="horizontal__content big:flex grid gap-y-[4rem]">
          <div
            v-for="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
            :key="num"
            class="horizontal__item border-[0.1rem] border-solid big:h-auto big:w-auto h-[80vh] w-full border-[#efefef] big:py-[5rem] xl:py-[7rem] big:px-[8rem] xl:px-[10rem] big:mr-[8rem]"
          >
            <div
              class="horizontal__num w-full text-[8rem] font-[900] text-[#f598af]"
            >
              <img :src="paint" class="w-full h-full" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->
    <div
      id="horizontal"
      class="horizontal w-full big:h-[100vh] big:overflow-hidden big:px-0 px-[1.5rem] py-[1rem] gap-[4rem] grid grid-rows-my-features  big:pb-0 pb-[8rem] relative"
    >
      <div
        class="w-full   sm:px-[5rem] xl:px-[14rem] h-max grid justify-items-center gap-[1rem] sm:gap-[10rem] sm:grid-cols-2"
      >
        <div class="w-max h-max gap-[1rem] sm:gap-[2rem] grid justify-items-start">
          <div
            class="container-tick"
          >
            <CheckBadgeIcon class="icon__tick" />
            <h1 class="text__tick">Maandeliks Betalen</h1>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-tick"
          >
            <CheckBadgeIcon class="icon__tick" />
            <h1 class="text__tick">100% Garantie</h1>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-tick"
          >
            <CheckBadgeIcon class="icon__tick" />
            <h1 class="text__tick">Professioneel Schilderwerk</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-max h-max gap-[1rem] sm:gap-[2rem] grid justify-items-start">
          <div
            class="container-tick"
          >
            <CheckBadgeIcon class="icon__tick" />
            <h1 class="text__tick">Zorgeloos onderhoud</h1>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-tick"
          >
            <CheckBadgeIcon class="icon__tick" />
            <h1 class="text__tick">Reiging & Glasbewassing</h1>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-tick"
          >
            <CheckBadgeIcon class="icon__tick" />
            <h1 class="text__tick">Ondafhankelike inspectie</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container row-span-2 w-[100%] h-full m-auto">
        <div class="horizontal__content h-full big:grid-flow-col grid gap-y-[4rem]">
          <div
            v-for="num in data"
            :key="num"
            class="horizontal__item  big:h-[60%] big:w-[28rem] h-[20rem] sm:h-[30rem]  w-full mr-[10rem]"
            >
            <!-- class="horizontal__item  big:h-[60%] big:w-[28rem] h-[20rem] sm:h-[30rem] w-full mr-[10rem]" -->
            <!-- class="horizontal__item border-[0.1rem] border-solid big:h-[60%] big:w-[28rem] h-[50%] w-full border-[#f598af] mr-[10rem]" -->
            <div class="horizontal__num w-full  h-full relative">
              <img :src="num.image" class="w-full  h-full object-cover" alt="" />
              <!-- <h1 class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2">{{ num.text }}</h1> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div
      id="horizontal"
      class="horizontal w-full big:px-0 px-[1.5rem] big:pb-0 pt-[4rem] pb-[8rem] h-[100vh] relative"
    >
      <div class="container w-[95%] m-auto">
        <div class="horizontal__content big:grid-flow-col grid gap-y-[4rem]">
          <div
            v-for="feature in featuresFor"
            :key="feature.id"
            class="horizontal__item border-[0.1rem] border-solid big:h-[30rem] big:w-[25rem] h-[80vh] w-full border-[#efefef] mr-[10rem]"
          >
            
            <div class="horizontal__num w-full h-full relative">
              <img
                :src="paint"
                class="w-full h-full "
                alt=""
              />
              <h1 class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2">{{ feature.name }}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->
  </div>
</template>
  

<style scoped>
.text__tick {
  @apply text-white text-[1rem] sm:text-[1.4rem];
}

.icon__tick {
  @apply text-[#f598af] text-[1.8rem] w-[2.2rem] h-[2.2rem];
}

.container-tick {
  @apply grid grid-cols-my-calc grid-flow-col  items-center text-left justify-items-start gap-[.7rem];
}

</style
```